# Is there anyway to make Magento zip/post code be upper case in PDF print outs?

Tags: invoice

I am using Fooman PDF customiser, although it can do a lot. I cannot seem to format my zip codes to be uppercase. I think I may be close but do not know the syntax.

When I go to Config > Customer Configuration > Address Templates > Pdf

I am given the option to change fields. How can I make the post code upper case. Syntax can be seen below. I have tried wrapping in html and it does not work.

`{{/if}}{{if postcode}}  {{var postcode}} {{/if}}|`